# android encode image with max size limit

Tags: android, image, size, limit

I need to encode an image to be JPEG and maximum file zise to be 300 K and send it as byte array. I make encoding :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
image = baos.toByteArray();
```

do you know how to limit the file size to 300K? maybe the solution is to make image quality lower, but sometimes(when the image is smaller) I may not need this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By repeatedly compressing with descending 'quality' values until the resulting byte[] length <= 300KB. There is no shortcut through this (AFAIK) but you can choose the quality values carefully and limit yourself to, say, a maximum of 4 compressions.

Comment: is file quality direct proportional to file size? I mean if I get the file size for quality 100 and file size for quality 99 and see differences at file size, may I compute the right quality?

Comment: Yes, with some variance. You can get a feel for the relationship from the graph here: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Quality_comparison_jpg_vs_saveforweb.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is to use a trial and test solution to find a compression value which gives you a value close to less than 300k.

File sizes for JPEG are highly dependent on the detail of the image so unless you're pictures are going to be of the same detail (no all black images etc) then the best compression rating will be different.

Maybe use a binary search style algorithm to find a *good* solution? Start at 50, then if too big, go down to 25 otherwise go up to 75. Then whenever you're within say 270-300 just stop?

Comment: is file quality direct proportional to file size? I mean if I get the file size for quality 100 and file size for quality 99 and see differences at file size, may I compute the right quality?

Comment: Hmm, I'm no expert, but you could presume so, at least initially. Some experimentation would help you modify the progression rates. But theres not going to be much difference at all between 99 and 100.